# Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 don't ask "Do you want to empty the trash" when I unmount an usb stick

Tags: trash, unmount

Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 don't ask "Do you want to empty the trash" when I unmount an usb stick.

Is it normal or is it a bug ?

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/14998/why-does-nautilus-ask-me-to-empty-the-trash-before-you-unmount?rq=1

Comment: Not really the same thing...

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.10 when I unmount a usb stick in nautilus it ask me if I want to empty the trash but it doesn't in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcouse It's a normal not bug.
But I think that system could prompt "Safly Eject blah blah"message to the user in this case.