# How to disable "Do you want to empty the trash before you unmount?" prompt in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, external-hdd, trash, 22.10

I have external USB disks formatted as NTFS, EXT4, etc. Recently Nautilus started asking me the following when I try to unmount the disk using Nautilus:

[image]

I *do* know that the Trash is kept on the removable disk and I *do not* want to empty the Trash every time I unmount the disk. So, how can I disable this annoying prompt that is displayed every time I unmount the disk?

Thunar File Manager, for example, *does not* ask this.

Note again: I *do* want to keep the Trash on the disk, but I just want to empty it *whenever I need*. I think that asking every time this to the user is prone to errors, because the user may click the **Empty Trash** selection by mistake.

Comment: Similar question from 12 years ago without solution: https://askubuntu.com/q/14998/558158. No true solution then, perhaps nowadays yes?